# Are there two tetrahedrons with the same volume that share their opposite edge lengths and arent the same or a different chirality of the same?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polyhedra, counterexamples, similarity

I have been coming up with an efficient way to decide if two tetrahedrons are similar. I believe that it is enough for a computer to check for the ordered by length list of pairs of opposite edges on both tetrahedron for them to be equal.

For example:
s = sqrt(1/2)

Tetrahedron 1: Edge lengths 1, 1, 1, 1, s, s, where s length edges are adjacent
Tetrahedron 2: Edge lengths 1, 1, 1, 1, s, s, where s length edges are opposite

These two tetrahedrons share the same volume and the same edge lengths, rendering both criteria  useless for determining similarity. But the opposite side edge length pairs of both are:

Tetrahedron 1: (1,1) (1,s) (1,s)
Tetrahedron 2: (1,1) (1,1) (s,s)

Which are not the same, just like both aren't similar. I included the volume because I know of a case that breaks this criteria by itself.

Tetrahedron 1: (1,0.6) (1,0.6) (1,0.6) with the 0.6 at the base
Tetrahedron 2: (1,0.6) (1,0.6) (1,0.6) with the 1 at the base

Both tetrahedron share the same opposite side lengths but their volume is radically different.

Is there a couple of tetrahedrons that breaks these criteria combined?
Is there a couple of tetrahedrons that have the same opposide edge lengths and the same volume and arent similar?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use the volume? Once you have the multiset of edge length, together with the information about which are paired, there are at most two different tetrahedrons. To tell them apart, it would suffice to record the side lengths of one of the faces.

Comment: There is a direct generalisation of Heron's formula for the volume.

Comment: verret, could you elaborate on your answer?

My multiset is ordered by size as can be seen in the second example. Two tetrahedrons might be drawn such that their points ABCD are not the same as those on an equal tetrahedron A'B'C'D' which is similar. How would you decide which face is drawn from which tetrahedron. I'm not exactly sure why there would be at most two dfferent tetrahedrons.

I am looking for a method to find similarity without checking each triangle face individually. Any hint on this would be awesome. 

Thanks in advance. This really means a lot to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the tetrahedral version of the classical triangle determination problem.  The rule of thumb is the one needs three conditions in the triangle case, six in yours.  There is a standard approach to such problems: One can assume the the vertices are are $A, B,C, D= (0,0,0), (a,0,0), (p,q,0), (r,s,t)$ and then translate the given data into a set of six equations in the corresponding variables.  An interesting example is when one is given one face, say ABC, and the areas of the other three. This leads to the fascinating result that if these are all equal in area to the former, then the tetrahedron is equifacial ("equi-areal implies equi-facial").  It wouldn't be appropriate for me to compute your case in detail but I imagine this method would work.  In many cases, one gets polynomial equations which can be solved by hand. Otherwise, one can use suitable software.